# (Done) req. reopen Being assigned to a position I don't want to + racism

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Being assigned to a position I don't want to + racism](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183749/being-assigned-to-a-position-i-dont-want-to-racism/183755#183755)

Very answerable.  Workplace bigtry/racism exists

Comment: Yes, a common enough problem. I'll make a judgement call on it.